# why getBodyContent().getString() return empty value in JSTL custom tag development using BodyTagSupport?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am using BodyTagSupport when I try to retrive body of my custom tag using 
getBodyContent() method of BodyTagSupport class I got empty value of getBodyContent().getString() evn though my tag has body.Is there any way to get bodycontent of my custom tag (using BodyTagSupport not SimpleTagSupport)?

I have custom tag as below

```
<custom:label>this is body of tag</custom:label>
```

in java class I am writing below code in doEndTag method

```
BodyContent bc = getBodyContent();
String body = bc.getString();
```

In tld file I have declared

```
<body-content>JSP</body-content>
```

but I am getting empty value in variable body.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `getBodyContent()` because it only works after the tag is initialized. Use `bodyContent` object instead and must be put inside `doEndTag`.

`pageContext.getOut().print(bodyContent.getString())`